# Need a suitable scripting language for below requirement of PDF documents

Tags: pdf

We have project requirement to validate PDF files which would contain below things for different policies.

1. Page Number
2. Images (screen shots)

Here we want to validate whether all the pages have images(screen shots), number of images in the PDF, image duplication and empty pages.

Please suggest me a suitable scripting language and way to fulfill our requirement.

Note:- Each policy will have different set screen shots and hence the total no of pages and image content for each PDF will vary.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: @kim ryan, how to get your email id? if you get time then please mail me those details to my id-hameed.udt@gmail.com

Comment: is there any solution?

Comment: plz guide me proceed further on this

Answer (score 1):

I've had to validate a lot of PDFs and found this toolkit very useful http://euske.github.io/pdfminer/index.html . It's written in Python, but comes with an excellent pdfdump utility which lets you look at the page number of each pages and all the elements in that page.

Having said that, I've only used it for text and am not sure how it identifies images.

Answer (score 0):

I would comment on Kim Ryan's answer, except that I don't have enough reputation to comment yet, which seems pretty silly.

In any case, I agree with Kim that pdfminer is probably your best bet overall.  However, I would mention that looking for images isn't all that difficult, and there is an "extract" example in the pdfrw library that will find images and pull them out to a separate PDF file.  I don't think it would be very hard to modify it to match images to page numbers.  I am the pdfrw author, so you can email me (address at github) if you have any questions on this.

Comment: give me ur mail id. I could not get it from github